# CUDA: Finding the array index in a 2D array allocated with cudaMallocPitch

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda, conways-game-of-life

I have been working on a game of life implementation with cuda. I want to find the array index of each element so i can calculate the neighbours for that element and so that i can write the new value to that array. All the things i found about this are working with pointers to rows and i just cant figure it out how this exactly translates to indexes. To give a better idea of what i mean i have to following code (some snippets):

```
#define THREADSPERBLOCK 1024
lifeState *d_gameStateInitial;
size_t d_gameStateInitial_pitch;
int sizeX = 100;
int sizeY = 100;

int numBlocks = ((sizeX * sizeY) % THREADSPERBLOCK) + 1;
int numThreadsPerBlock;

if(numBlocks == 1)
{
    numThreadsPerBlock = sizeX * sizeY;
}
else
{
    numThreadsPerBlock = THREADSPERBLOCK;
}

cudaMallocPitch((void **)&d_gameStateInitial, &d_gameStateInitial_pitch, sizeX * sizeof(lifeState), sizeY);

doTheGame<<<numBlocks, numThreadsPerBlock>>>(d_gameStateInitial, d_gameStateInitial_pitch, d_gameStateNew, d_gameStateNew_pitch, sizeX, sizeY);
```

The "lifestate *" is simply a struct containing an dead/alive enum. Both arrays, the initial and new ones are malloc'd exactly the same way. In the doTheGame kernel i now want to know how to calculate the index, i was thinking about something like this but i think it is wrong:

```
__global__ void doTheGame(lifeState *initialArray, size_t initialArrayPitch,
                      lifeState *newArray, size_t newArrayPitch,
                      int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
int initialArrayThreadIndex = (blockIdx.x * initialArrayPitch) + threadIdx.x;
int newArrayThreadIndex = (blockIdx.x * initialArrayPitch) + threadIdx.x;
}
```

Everything i found thus far are basically all the same as the cudaMallocPitch example:

```
  T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;
```

But i just cant see how that translates to blocks, threads and x and y exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really see a question here. What exactly is it you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a `double data[]` array like this:

```
A  B  C  D  x  x  x  x
E  F  G  H  x  x  x  x
```

Then `data[0] = A`, `data[1] = B` etc.

This might be the result of allocating a 2x4 array with a pitch allocation of 64 bytes (thus the 4 extra `x` entries in each row).  Let's suppose each element in the above array is a `double` quantity.

Now suppose I have a kernel, and I am launching an array of 2x4 threads, one per valid element (the `x` elements are not valid - they are the extra allocations to satisfy the pitch requirement, which is arbitrarily chosen for this example to be 64 bytes).

In this kernel, I could create an x and y index as follows:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x +blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
int idy = threadIdx.y +blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
```

Each thread can then access its respective element as follows.

Since the `pitch` quantity returned by `cudaMallocPitch` is in bytes, we need to compute a row offset first, using `char` pointer arithmetic:

```
double *rowptr = (double *)((char *)data + idy*pitch);
```

We can then access an element on that row like this:

```
rowptr[idx] = 0.0;
```

If I want a thread to access an element other than the one corresponding to its thread indices, the calculations are similar.

For example to set element `G` (i.e. element (1,2)) to zero in the above `data` array, I could do:

```
double *rowptr = (double *)((char *)data + 1*pitch);
rowptr[2] = 0.0;
```

Comment: I asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296947/how-do-you-iterate-through-a-pitched-cuda-array) before finding this one, but I can't follow your example. You don't seem to be checking if `rowptr` is in the array, which would only work if you've carefully manipulated the number of threads and blocks. Also, it would seem like you go through padding elements blindly. Can you post a more complete example?